# Array seems to be null, values were read in from text file (fixed duplication)

Tags: java, arrays, error-handling

```js
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
// The "FileProcess2" class.
/*September 25, 2016
 Programmer: Toni L
 This is a program to enter in expense values from a specific text file(previously created) and sort them, then add them to get the total. Also calculates the average expense value.*/
public class FileProcess2
{
 //Integer to contain number of rows in text file
 static int days = 0;
 static double hold = 0.00;
 //Method to take the double array that contains the expense value and using a bubble sort, organize them from greatest to least then return sorted array
  public static Double[] Organiser(Double[] expenses)throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

   
   for(int i=0 ; i<days ; i++){
    for(int y=0 ; y<(days-1) ; y++){
     if(expenses[y] < expenses[y+1]){
      hold = expenses[y];
      expenses[y] = expenses[y+1];
      expenses[y+1] = hold;
     }
    }
   }

   return expenses;
  }
 public static void main (String[] args)throws IOException
 {
  
  //File Reader to read in the contents of the file
  BufferedReader rF = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("expenses.txt"));
  //Actual number of lines in text file is generated
  while(rF.readLine() != null){
   days ++;
  }

  //Declaring string array to enter values from text file
  Double expenses[] = new Double[days];
  while(rF.readLine() != null)
  {
  }
  rF.close();
  //Declaring new double array to enter the values from the text file
  

  //Runs Organiser Class
  Organiser(expenses);
  //Printing values in table format, with column headings.
  System.out.println("Number"+"\t"+"Expenses");
  for(int s = 0; s<days ; s++){
   System.out.println((s+1)+"\t"+ expenses[s]);
  }


 }
 
 //Calculates the total of the expenses as well as the average/
 public static void totaler(double[] expenses)throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
  double hold = 0.00, total= 0.00, average= 0.00;
  for(int u = 0; u<days; u++){
   hold = expenses[u];
   total = hold + total;
   average = (total/days);
  }
  //Outputs the total as well as the average.
  System.out.println("The total value of Shelley's purchases is: "+total);
  System.out.println("The average value of Shelley's purchases is: "+ average);



 }
}
```

When running the program, I cant seem to get it to read in the numbers from the text file properly, because it always gives me a     `NullPointerException` . I read the documentation for that exception, and I know that it means that my array called `expenses[]` is null, but I'm not sure how to give it values. Can someone help me?

Comment: I recommend that you try to improve the formatting of your code that you post in here and your code in general. Good formatting including using an indentation style that is uniform and consistent will help others (**us**!) to better understand your code, and more importantly, it will help **you** to better understand your code and thus fix your own bugs. Also it shows that you're willing to put in extra effort to make it easier for the volunteers here to help you, and that effort is **much** appreciated.

Comment: Which line is line 31?

Comment: Side note: `d < days` is much cleaner and more standard than `d <= (days - 1)`.

Comment: The duplication mark is a great hint, also the documentation of BufferedReader.readLine() and what happens when the stream is at its end.